# Generic<T>() vs Generic(System.Type). Generics vs Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Where is it more appropriate to use

```
class Entity<T> {}

new Entity<User>()
```

as opposed to

```
class Entity
{
   public Entity(System.Type type) 
   {
   }
}

new Entity(typeof(User))
```

I realized the significance of System.Type after dealing with reflection and code generation. After a month of development and getting familiar, I look back at my choices with skepticism.

This would probably not apply to you if you do not need reflection.

Comment: You use generics if generics solve your problem, and you use reflection if reflection solves your problem. Which problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic approach `Entity<T>` has the ability to use generic type constraints to enforce both rules and features at compile-time (i.e. `T` must have a public parameterless constructor and be a reference-type, for example). It doesn't need any storage space for the type on each instance, since `Entity<X>` and `Entity<Y>` are discreet types - but as a re-statement of that: you cannot have a heterogeneous `List<Entity<?>>` (unless you have a common base-type) for the same reason.

It is much harder to use generics if the type is known only at run-time.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm writing a tool to analyze code and generate warnings based on contextual usage of language features. That is good insight.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you have inside of Entity. Do you have any fields of type T or parameters to methods of type T in the Entity class? If you are only ever doing `typeof(T)` inside Entity then it probably would be simpler to pass in a System.Type like in your second example.

Another difference would be that you can use constraints with generics, so you could do `class Entity<T> where T: ISomeInterface`

Answer (score 0):

If you use second approach you will have type cast the user object(which you will have, most probably) every time  in entity class. Where as if you use generic i.e. first approach you will not require this.